# Inserting a pdf into latex with additional text

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I need to add a content of a pdf file as an appendix to my thesis. I do this with

```
\chapter{Material used in Turing test experiment}
\label{ch:turing_materials}

\includepdf[pages=-,scale=0.8]{images/task.pdf}
```

Unfortunately, this pushes the content of the pdf file to the next page, so I get almost empty page only with the title and it does not look nice.
Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Does the option `scale=0.8` maybe not shrink the first page of the file `task.pdf` sufficiently to make it fit on the same page as the chapter header? What happens if you insert just the first page of `task.pdf` (saved to a separate file named, say, `task01.pdf`) using an `\includegraphics` instruction (requires the `graphicx` package)?

Comment: `\includepdf` always uses full pages: that's the point. If you want to use a PDF as a graphic then as @Mico says `\includegraphics` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the chapter heading to the first page of the imported PDF try

```
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.8,pagecommand={\chapter{Material used in Turing test experiment}\label{ch:turing_materials}\hfill}]{images/task.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,scale=0.8,pagecommand={\hfill}]{images/task.pdf}
```